# samba shares reject samba username and password from Windows

Tags: remapping

I'm running Ubuntu Server 12.04 LTS on a HP Micro server. I've edited smb.conf and added a share called files right at the end of the file  (as per hours of googling) as below

[files] 
Path = /media/files
Read only = no
Browsable = yes
Valid users = %S
Comment = Shared Files

I have a user called brett with a password. Brett also has a home directory, which I CAN access via windows as a mapped drive, but I can't get the "files" share to work.

What am I doing wrong please? I'm a noob at Ubuntu/Linux but far from a noob at Windows

Answer (score 4):

You probably need to add the user to samba: `smbpasswd -a myuser`

Comment: Nup, double checked that. But thanks very much for responding so quickly :-)

Comment: This is what I was missing, as a more basic Ubuntu newbie. Thanks user2060608

Answer (score 1):

Turned out system-config-samba run from the terminal as root did it. Samba config GUI doesn't accept any password. That's where I went wrong. Run it within terminal, and away you go!